# Next number in the sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

What is the next number in this sequence?

0, 6, 12, 19, 27, 35, 45, 54, 63, ?

Good luck!

HINT:

> I've always preferred digital watches over analogue.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this, but please check [Number Sequence Puzzles - What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712/5373). There's not really much to get hold of here: it's just a bare sequence of numbers with no hints or clues.

Comment: good point. I've added a hint.

Comment: I am sorry guys this turned out to be a bad puzzle. I wish I could delete it but I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> 73

Reasoning:

> So, the consecutive differences are incremental via +1. So, I perhaps have the idea of having 73 as the next number, since that will increment the difference by +1.
> Since, 6-0=6,
>  19-12=7,
>  35-27=8,
>  54-45=9,
>  73-63=10

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> 54

Reasoning:

> Because each alternate number is increasing by the starting difference but adding 3 with each progressive number in the series?
> Like +12,+15,+18.
> And likewise +13, +16, and therefore +19.

Comment: You got the right answer, but for the wrong reason. I will add more terms to the sequence to make it clearer.